# Paperclip image medium size broken to missing link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am doing the One Month Rails Course. I am using Rails 4. My Github folder is: https://github.com/phanatuan/pinteresting

I use the Paperclip gem. In the App/views/pins/show.html.erb, I want to show the pins picture at medium size. I passed the code `<%= image_tag @pin.image.url %>`. The browser shows the pin with the un-resized pictures. When i pass ":medium" into the code as such `<%= image_tag @pin.image.url(:medium) %>`, the browser shows the missing image.

I check all the documentations and follow closely the instructions but I could not find the mistake.

Really Appreciate your help

Tuan

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to diagnose this without seeing the code, but my best guess is that you did not declare the style :medium for the attached file in your model.

Try this:

```
has_attached_file :image,
                  :styles => { :medium => "120x120>" }
```

Also, make sure that you specify a :style in your path declaration for the file.